# Why is MFCreateMediaSession not supported for Metro apps?

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, ms-media-foundation

I'm learning Media Foundation and would like to use it from a Metro app.  Unfortunately, MFCreateMediaSession is not supported for Metro apps.  Why is that?  How would a Metro app create a media session to, say, play a stream of PCM audio generated on the fly by the app?

Comment: Welcome to Windows 8 where many of the APIs you once loved are missing, often for no good reason

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it is by design that Metro apps are not to create their own media sessions this way.  The following answer provided by James Dailey, of Microsoft, on [an MSDN Forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithnativecode/thread/fa0000e2-9969-42d8-9a2e-aa5684689ade/) (additional markup by me) provides some insight:

> Here are two options for you:
>
> 1) Use [WASAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371455%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and pump your synthesized PCM audio directly to the
>   audio manager (preferred)
>
> 2) Create a custom source that can plug into the [Media Foundation
>   Media Engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/Hh447918)
>
> Either approach will work as expected. You will need to carefully
>   review each method and compare them against your software
>   requirements. For most synthesized audio scenarios, using the [WASAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371455%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
>   is recommended.

He later clarified:

> Q. [WASAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371455%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):  I'm missing one crucial piece in my understanding -- how to do the initial activation/instantiation of the required objects to access audio devices.  How do I even get a handle to an audio device when [IMMDevice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371395.aspx) isn't supported for Metro style apps?
>
> A. Code listed below:

```cpp
Platform::String^ id = Windows::Media::Devices::MediaDevice::GetDefaultAudioCaptureId(Windows::Media::Devices::AudioDeviceRole::Console);
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IAudioClient> pAudioClient = NULL;  
ActivateAudioInterface( id->Data(), __uuidof( IAudioClient ), (void**)&pAudioClient );
```

> Q. [Media Foundation Media Engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/Hh447918):  from studying the [real-time communication sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Simple-Communication-Sample-eac73290), it seems the approach for play/record would be the following -- have I got it right so far?
>
> - Playback:  Use [Windows.Media.MediaExtensionManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.mediaextensionmanager.aspx) to register a
>     scheme (in the example, it's "stsp://") handler which creates a
>     custom source whenever a URL with this scheme is navigated to.
> - Recording:  Implement a custom sink and use [Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture.StartRecordToCustomSinkAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700855.aspx) to capture media to it.
>
> A. Yes this seems like a reasonable approach.